# Create this type of gradient background?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background, pixel, pixel-art

I'm trying to create a pixelart picture and I'm having problems with background. I need to do this effect:

[image]

Is a gradient but I think is not created with Aseprite Gradient Tool. And in PS I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Can you explain what *specifically* you are struggling with? That gradient, in general, is just a straight linear gradient - [fairly easy in Photoshop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDkZY.png). Are you trying to mimic the banding or something?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to mimic the bandings. The pixel-art effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is for Photoshop, I don't know much about Asperite, sorry.

1. You could create a custom gradient by sampling the colour stops from your example image. Click "New" to save your custom gradient. You'll need it for the next step.

Something like this

[image]

2. Use the gradient tool to make your background using the custom gradient you made previously.
3. For the banding, do *Image > Mode > Indexed*, and use the settings shown below, something like 11 colours should do the trick. You can set it to however many you want.

[image]

4. Revert to RGB by doing *Image > Mode > RGB*

Comment: Who is the best? You are the best! Thank you man! :)

Comment: @CarlosPérez Well, I don't know about that LOL . . . but glad you liked it!!